# pysnmp output format issue

Tags: python, pysnmp

I am trying to get some snmp variables from cisco routers using `PySNMP` but I am getting a hex output using `prettyprint` instead of the output I get from my normal snmp browser.

I have tried multiple encode `(hex, utf-8 and ascii`) and without encode, always not what I was expecting.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Start discovery of `10.148.8.15`

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = 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

   result = {'error': 1, 'value': "default"}
cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(
cmdgen.CommunityData(community),
cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((destination, 161)),
cmdgen.MibVariable(oid)
```

)

```
# Check for errors and print out results
if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
else:
    if errorStatus:
        result['error'] = 1
        # print('%s at %s' % (
        #     errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
        #     errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
        #     )
        # )
    else:
        result['error'] = 0
        for name, val in varBinds:
            print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
            result['value'] = val.prettyPrint().encode("ascii")
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because Cisco SNMP Agent reports control characters (\n) what may potentially screw your script's output. There are several ways to handle this:

1. Pass `lookupMib=True` like shown in [this example](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/examples/hlapi/v1arch/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/enable-mib-lookup.py). Then pysnmp would try to look up proper output format for this particular OID at MIB. For this to work pysnmp must be able to find and load pysnmp-formatted MIB file(s).
2. Add some code to trigger a hex string decoder when 0x prefix is seen:

   ```
   s =     '436973636f...06d63707265'

   print(''.join([ chr(int(s[x:x+2], 16)) for x in range(0, len(s), 2) ]))
   ```

Cisco IOS Software, IOS-XE Software ...Compiled Tue 25-Feb-14 11:36 by mcpre